# Extracting data from simple html mail

Tags: php, html

I'am woking on a application where I need to extract data from emails, what is the best and cleanest approach?. My email is in the following format:

```
Initials: F<br>
Last name: Bar<br>
Phone: 06 12345678<br>
<p>
    Message: This is a simple message
<p>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? How is your code obtaining this?

Comment: I've tried fixing it with a regex and this does work fine but I was wondering if there was a better solution for it. The regex I used was `/Initials: (.*?)<br>/ `and using a preg_match I get the first group, (.*?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `simple_html_dom` to do this job

Documentation:- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/